# Find a list of max values in a text file using awk

Tags: arrays, awk, syntax, max

I am new to awk and I cannot figure out the correct syntax for the task I am working on.

I have a text file which looks something like this (the content is always sorted but is not always the same, so I cannot hard code the index of the array):

```
27 abc123
27 abd333
27 dce123
23 adb234
21 abc789
18 bcd213
```

So apparently the max is 27. However, I want my output to be:

```
27 abc123
27 abd333
27 dce123
```

and not the first row only.

The second column is just there, my code always sorts the text file based on the first column.

My code right now set the max as the first value (27 for example), and as it reads through the lines, it stores only the rows with the max values in an array and eventually print out the output.

```
awk 'BEGIN {max=$1} {if(($1)==max) a[NR]=($0)} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read fields in a `BEGIN` block, since it's executed before the file is read.

To find the first record, use the pattern `NR == 1`. `NR` is the number of the current record. To find the other records, just check whether `$1` equals the max value.

```
NR == 1 { max = $1 }
$1 == max { print }
```

Since your input is always sorted, you can optimise this program by exiting after reading all the records with the max value:

```
$1 != max { exit }
```

Comment: So I put the 3 lines of code above in a .awk file. Hower, when I run it, it does not really "exit". For example, whenever it finishes running, a new line in the terminal would appear for me to type in new commands. But in this case, nothing showed up. Even when I tried another print statement. The output file is also blank.

awk -f prob.awk > outFile
awk '{print $0}' < outFile

Comment: Nevermind I made a slight mistake. Thank you very much!